# 納得 and 一良好な usage in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, words

What is the meaning of 「納得」 and 「一良好な」 in the following sentence?

> 仁の家族。仁の人柄がここで育ったのも納得のサムドラ内一良好な家族関係・人柄の一族。旧家で名家。

I think that 「一」 in this case is similar to 「一番」, so I would translate 「一良好な」 as "the best", "the favourite". As for 「納得」, I know it translates as "consent", "agreement", "compliance", but I don't understand its meaning here.
The context is a character's family profile in a manga called "Samurai Drive" (「サムライドライブ」, abbreviated to 「サムドラ」here). Here's my attempt:

> Jin's family. It's the family in which Jin developed his personality, and also the family with the best relationships and personalities within those agreed(?) in Samurai Drive.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`～ + も/は + 納得だ/納得がいく/納得できる` means "(therefore) ～ seems reasonable/legitimate/understandable", "so, that explains why ～", etc. `～` is a consequence part, which is often undesirable and/or unlikely.

> - 高級な素材を使っているので、値段が高いのは納得がいきます。
> - このレストランの料理はとてもおいしい。なかなか予約が取れないのも納得だ。
> - ここの家族の人柄は素晴らしいので、仁の人柄がここで育ったのも納得だ。

`納得の/納得がいく/納得できる + (noun)` is "(noun) that convinces someone of ～", "reasonable (noun)", "satisfactory (noun)":

> - 納得の値段 reasonable price
> - 納得のいく説明 = 納得がいく説明 satisfactory explanation

Put together:

> - なかなか予約が取れないのも納得のレストラン
>     the restaurant that it is rightly/understandably hard to make a reservation at
> - 仁の人柄がここで育ったのも納得の素晴らしい一族
>     the wonderful tribe that convinces me of the fact that Jin's personality was developed here

---

`(place) + 一【いち】` means "best in (place)", "number one in (place)". Parse the sentence as `サムドラ内一 + 良好`, not `サムドラ内 + 一良好`.

> - 日本一【にほんいち】高い山 the highest mountain in Japan
> - フランス一の葡萄畑 the greatest vineyard in France
> - サムドラ(内)一良好な家族関係 the best family relationship in Samurai Drive

内 before 一 is not common.